# How to overcome the problem in get_dummies method

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to machine learning field. I used get_dummies method for categorical features into numerical. But i found this error!

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'Make'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-1192137dc95f> in <module>
17 
18 #oneHot encodding in Transmssion
---> 19 dummy4= pd.get_dummies(df['Make'])
20 df= pd.concat([df, dummy4], axis=1)
21 df= df.drop('Transmission', axis=1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
2801             if is_integer(indexer):
2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'Make'
```

i used this code

```
#oneHot encodding in make
dummy1= pd.get_dummies(df['Make'])
df= pd.concat([df, dummy1], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Make', axis=1)

#oneHot encodding in Model
dummy2= pd.get_dummies(df['Model'])
df= pd.concat([df, dummy2], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Model', axis=1)

#oneHot encodding in Vehicle-Class
dummy3= pd.get_dummies(df['Vehicle-Class'])
df= pd.concat([df, dummy3], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Vehicle-Class', axis=1)

#oneHot encodding in Transmssion
dummy4= pd.get_dummies(df['Transmission'])
df= pd.concat([df, dummy4], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Transmission', axis=1)

#oneHot encodding in Fuel-Type
dummy5= pd.get_dummies(df['Fuel-Type'])
df= pd.concat([df, dummy5], axis=1)
df= df.drop('Fuel-Type', axis=1)
```

for the last encoding for 'Fuel-type' it was done correctly. but for others it didn't work.

this is the link for my dataset

https://www.kaggle.com/sethirishabh/fuel-consumption

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. It gives you the correct output.

The reason for the above error is you may have run that code for the second time on the same data frame. Since you have already dropped the 'Make' column form the data frame in the first time it says there is no column in the data frame.

Restart and Run the code from the very beginning. :) :)